# Protobuf error:Protocol message tag had invalid wire type

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am having the following error when trying to read the message in java

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidWireType(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:78)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:498)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$Builder.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessage.java:438)

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("F:/Newfolder/sample_message.txt");
Nt nlc = Nt.parseFrom(fis);

if(nlc.hasMessageId())
{
    System.out.println("MessageId: "+nta2sse.getMessageId());
}
```

I am getting exception at `if(nlc.hasMessageId())`

---

Here is full stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidWireType(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:78)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:498)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$Builder.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessage.java:438)
    at com.soeasy.aanta.nta.sse.NtaSse$Nta2Sse$Builder.mergeFrom(NtaSse.java:523)
    at com.soeasy.aanta.nta.sse.NtaSse$Nta2Sse$Builder.mergeFrom(NtaSse.java:1)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:1)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:212)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:746)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:1)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:282)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessage.java:760)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:288)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(AbstractMessage.java:752)
    at com.soeasy.aanta.nta.sse.NtaSse$Nta2Sse.parseDelimitedFrom(NtaSse.java:338)
    at com.soeasy.aanta.nta.sse.NtaSseServer.main(NtaSseServer.java:60)
```

and the sample _message.txt has the following:

```
message_id: 1
batch_meas_update {
  device_update {
    unique_device_id {
      device_type: ME
      device_id: 161
    }
    meas_update {
      override_status: OVERRIDE_INACTIVE
      bad_data_status: GOOD_DATA
      scada_status: SCADA_ACTIVE
      weight: 1.0
      value: 406.596
    }
  }
}
```

It is in accordance with.proto file

Thanks

Comment: (I merged the second question into this one)

Comment: Maybe not a corrupted file, but a newer protobuf version

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I very much doubt that you're getting the exception there - I'd expect you to get it in `parseFrom`. Could you post the *full* stack trace instead of just the first three lines?

I strongly suspect you've basically got a broken file. The fact that you've given a `.txt` extension for what should be a *binary* file is somewhat suspect... what does the file actually look like? You don't use `parseFrom` like this to parse an ASCII representation of a protobuf message.

EDIT: As per the question linked in the comment, you're trying to parse a *text* file using a method designed for *binary* data.

You want to use something like:

```
// Use the normal try/finally for closing reliably
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis, "ASCII");

Nt.Builder builder = Nt.newBuilder();
TextFormat.merge(reader, builder);
Nt nt = builder.build();
```

Comment: Thank You very much. Now it is working fine. I spent a whole day but not able to find the error. thanks a lot

Comment: This answer saved the day for me. If anyone is parsing from json instead of txt like me, you could use JsonFormatter like this:

JsonFormat jsonFormat = new JsonFormat();
jsonFormat.merge(targetStream, builder);

where targetStream is an InputStream (byteArray basically)

Answer (score 5):

When I see users report this type of message, it almost always means they've corrupted the file. Starting from a `.txt` is a worrying sign, as protocol buffers is a binary format that cannot be represented in a text encoding (unless you count base-64 etc).

Another common cause of this is over-writing a file with *less* data and not trimming the excess. Since protocol buffers includes (for the root message) neither a length prefix nor a terminator, any excess data (essentially garbage now) from previous file contents will be processed. This is a bad thing; you must always trim your outputs when over-writing.

Comment: @ Marc GravellSO is there any way to make this text file as a binary file

Comment: SO is there any way to make this text file as a binary file

Comment: I am not able to understand what do u mean by over writing and what should i do to trim. thanks for your helo

Comment: @ravi - ah, you're using the secondary *text* format (er... why?) - then simply as Jon notes you are using the wrong API