# Read protobuff text file using protobuff-csharp port

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers

I am using the protobuf-csharp-port library to write and read messages in text.

I am able to write the messages in text using the following code, but I am not able to find any examples of how I could read this message back into a proto buff type definition.

I am using the below code to create the person directory text file.

```
Person p1 = Person.CreateBuilder().SetId(1).SetName("Person1").Build();
Person p2 = Person.CreateBuilder().SetId(2).SetName("Person2").Build();

PeopleDir pd = PeopleDir.CreateBuilder().AddPerson(p1).AddPerson(p2).Build();

File.AppendAllText(@"C:\PersonDirectory.txt", pd.ToString());
```

The text file now looks as below

```
Person {
  Id: 1
  Name: "Person1"
}
Person {
  Id: 2
  Name: "Person2"
}
```

How can I now read this text data back into the Person definition?

Also, when trying to read this file by using following code, I get an error "Protocol message tag had invalid wire type."

```
using (Stream inputStream = new FileStream(@"C:\PersonDirectory.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    PeopleDir pd = PeopleDir.CreateBuilder().MergeFrom(inputStream).Build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling some more about this error I found a solution for my problem based on the answer for a question on StackOverflow.

For the benefit for anyone else trying to do the same I am posting my solution below.

I used a similar approach to get the solution as the answer to below SO question
[Protobuf error:Protocol message tag had invalid wire type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138721/protobuf-errorprotocol-message-tag-had-invalid-wire-type)

So in my case the code to read back a person text file in protobuff format would be:

```
using (TextReader inputStream = new StreamReader(new FileStream(@"C:\PersonDirectory.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.ASCII))
{
                PersonDir.Builder personDirBuilder = PersonDir.CreateBuilder();
                TextFormat.Merge(inputStream, personDirBuilder);
                PersonDir pd = personDirBuilder.Build();
}
```