# How can I solve this Hadoop core-site.xml problem?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, ip, port, namenode

I'm using Hadoop-2.7.6 and want to build fully-distributed.
I gave 3 VM servers and they can only use 32222 port.

In /etc/hosts,

```
1xx.xxx.xxx.xx1 namenode
1xx.xxx.xxx.xx2 slave1
1xx.xxx.xxx.xx3 slave2
```

Then in core-site.xml,

```
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://namenode:32222</value>
</property>
```

But when I executed `hdfs dfs -ls`,

```
ls: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "hostname/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; destination host is: "namenode":32222
```

this error message occur.
Moreover, when I executed `start-all.sh`

```
Starting namenodes on [namenode]
```

then other slave node occur time out.
How can solve this problem..?

Answer (score 0):

Property `fs.default.name` has been deprecated and replaced by `fs.defaultFS`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30480984/7857701

```xml
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFs</name>
    <value>hdfs://namenode:32222</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I already changed fs.defaut.name into fs.defautFS, but it doesn't work yet...

Comment: I got [this](https://kb.informatica.com/solution/23/Pages/73/612472.aspx). It's saying This issue can occur if the Hive table's data partition file is corrupted.

Also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138805/7857701